# Thymeleaf same date format in th:text and th:field

Tags: spring, date, jpa, thymeleaf

I have an entity which contains a date field, 'validFrom'. I want to display the date 2 times, once in a table where the date is readonly, once in an input field where the date can be set. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to correctly display the date in both cases using the client Locale, which uses this format: dd.MM.yyyy

Here is the jpa entity (irrelevant annotations left out):

```
public class Category {

    @javax.persistence.Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private java.sql.Date validFrom;

    ....

}
```

Here is the table displaying the entities:

```
<tr th:each="item: ${allItems}">
    <td><span th:text="${{item.validFrom}}"></span></td>
```

Here is the page where the user can create the entity and enter the date:

```
<form th:action="@{/categories/edit}" th:object="${entity}" method="post">
    <input type="date" th:field="*{validFrom}"/>
```

With this configuration I get the correct format (dd.MM.yyyy) in the input field but the wrong format in the text field (yyyy-MM-dd).

When I change the annotation in the entity to

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
```

I get the correct format in the text field, but the input field remains empty with the following error message in my browser console:

> The specified value "18.05.2018" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

The last thing I tried is approach one using thymeleaf's #dates.format(date) in the text field. Unfortunately this also appends HH:MM:SS, which I don't want.

Now I could of course pass the format 'dd.MM.yyyy' as second parameter but then it's hardcoded into my html which blows i18n. So I tried to pass #{date.format}, which I specified in my messages.properties but this caused a parsing error.

> Expression [#dates.format(item.validFrom, #{date.format})] @31:
>   EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to use a filter?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34858989/wrong-date-format-when-submit-spring-form

Comment: I think the problem is `type="date"` do you need that?

Comment: did you try `th:text="${#dates.format(item.validFrom, 'dd.MM.yyyy')}"`

Comment: @Metroids if I want to have a standardized date input I think I do need it, no?

Comment: @want2learn As I said, I don't want to break internationalization. If I hardcode the format in German locale, I can't use the same html for a different locale.

Comment: @BennettDams No I did not try it yet. I was hoping this could be solved using Spring/Thymeleaf alone without pulling an additional dependency. If there is no other solution, I will try the filter.